# How to get rid of warning "Access is Private" when accessing from within the class that defines it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, clone

I have a class with a protected property, that is only ever accessed from within this class.  Thus, the compiler rightly says that access can be private.

However, I also have a `clone()` method, which creates a new value for that property so that the clone has a separate instance of that property.  But when the access on the variable is private, the line that accesses it from the clone method (in the same file, mind you) is complaining that the property is private.

What do I have to change to this code so that I don't get a warning when I try to set a new value for the property?

```
public abstract class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> implements Cloneable {

  private Gizmo bar = new Gizmo();

  @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
  public T clone() {
    try {
      T copy = (T) super.clone();
      copy.bar = new Gizmo();
      return copy;
    }
    catch ( CloneNotSupportedException e ) {
      // will never happen
      return (T) this;
    }

}
```

And while we are on the subject, is there a better way to get rid of the unchecked cast exception other than just suppressing it when I know it will always succeed?

Comment: "*Thus, the compiler rightly says that access can be private.*" - Are you sure you mean the compiler? Not your IDE, i.e. IntelliJ? As an aside: You should really not use `Cloneable` [since it is broken](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Comment: You are right, it's the IDE.

Comment: You may want to [edit] your question and change the tags accordingly.

Comment: As for using cloneable, how can I avoid it when I'm trying to make a copy of some unknown derived class, and then modify the value of one of the internal properties?  I can't say "new T()"

Comment: Changed the tags.  Better?

Comment: There is no simple solution for the clone problem. First off, using the default `Cloneable` interface bears the problem that `clone()` always returns an `Object`. Second, interfaces are somewhat misfit for the purpuse since every subclass of a `Cloneable` must implement the `clone()` aswell, which leads to nasty `CloneNotSupportedException`s in case a sub-class explicitly does not want to be cloned. Providing a copy-constructor does not help since constructors are not inherited.